# I restarted docker but now nginx won't connect. What can i do?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I restarted docker with the command: 
    sudo systemctl restart docker

Now, my nginx won't connect. I haven't changed any of the nginx config files and have tried sudo service nginx restart but nothing

[image]

Comment: Your nginx is in docker container?

Comment: yes it is. nginx status says this: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument

Comment: what about delete this file and restart container again?

Comment: just did that, check the image i posted in the question with my status. Not sure what'd going on. Looks like it's up and running